# How to emit to show/hide loader overlay?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, eventemitter

I'm making a loader component for when my API calls are loading in. I'd like it to be a container I can place around anything. But I am very new to emits and am not quite sure how to use it in this scenario. What am I doing wrong?

This is my component AppLoader.vue:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
let loading = ref(false);

const showLoader = () => {
  loading.value = !loading;
};
</script>

<template>
  <div
    v-if="loading"
    :class="loading ? 'loading' : ''"
    class="loader f-height f-width"
  >
    LOADER WHOOOOOO
  </div>
  <slot></slot>
</template>

<style src="./app-loader.css" scoped lang="postcss" />
```

app-loader.css:

```
.loader {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.loading {
    display: block;
}
```

On the page I want to use it:

```
<AppLoader>Some stuff that takes a while to load....</AppLoader>
```

And in the script of my page:

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
const emit= defineEmits(["showLoader"])

onMounted(() => {
  emit("showLoader", true); // Show the loader by adding a display:block class
  // Fetch all my API calls and process the information on the page
  emit("showLoader", false) // Hide the loader by removing the display:block class
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try with prop that you send from parent component and watch it in loader:

```js
const { ref, onMounted, watch } = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const isLoading = ref(true)
    onMounted(() => {
      setTimeout(() => isLoading.value = false, 5000)
    })
    return { isLoading }
  }
})
app.component('loader', {
  template: `
    <div
      v-if="loading"
      :class="loading ? 'loading' : ''"
      class="loader f-height f-width"
    >
      LOADER WHOOOOOO
    </div>
    <slot></slot>
  `,
  props: {
    load: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true
    }
  },
  setup(props) {
    const loading = ref(props.load);
    watch(
      () => props.load,
      (newValue) => loading.value = newValue
    );
    return { loading }
  }
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```css
.loader {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.loading {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <loader :load="isLoading">Some stuff that takes a while to load....</loader>
</div>
```